# Clone dynamic object using Entity Framework Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'd like to be able to clone an object and its children.

In a previous project (EF6.0) an implementation like this worked fine;

```
Job job = db.Jobs.AsNoTracking()
                .Include("Columns")
                .Include("Exclusions")
                .Include("Batches")
                .Include("OtherColumns")
                .First(x => x.Id == (int)jobId);
db.Jobs.Add(job);
db.SaveChanges();
```

A new job was added to the database, as well as new children.

Now in a new project (EFCore3.1.3) I'm using a Repository pattern and trying to create a clone function;

```
public async Task<int> CloneByIdAsync(int id, string childrenObjectsToInclude)
{
    var query = _dbContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().AsQueryable(); // Get as no tracking so all objects can be saved as new (no ids)
    string[] includes = childrenObjectsToInclude.Split(';');
    foreach (string include in includes)
        query = query.AsNoTracking().Include(include);

    T thing = query.AsNoTracking().First(x => x.Id == id); // We have to get the thing we want
    
    await _dbContext.Set<T>().AddAsync(thing); // Add to the collection
    return await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(); // Save the changes - should generate all new ids and items
}
```

You can see I've tried to use `AsNoTracking()` in a couple of places, but this doesn't seem to work. It retrieves the object and it's children just fine, but when trying to add to the database it's trying to insert the object with the same Id and so I get a SQL Exception.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Did you try setting the Id with the default value (0), before insert?

Comment: No I didn't try that yet, because I would then also have to do something to traverse all the children and set their Id's to 0 as well, which I'm not sure how I would do. I'm hoping there is an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few things I eventually conceded that you need to set the object's Id to 0 in EF Core for it to be treated as a new object. I used something like the below, and manually detached all the child entities that I wanted on the cloned object. With their Id's all set to 0 when save changes occurs a new set of child objects will also be created correctly linked to the new parent object.

```
var project = await _dbContext.Projects
                .Include("FloorAreaTypes")
                .Include("FloorAreaTypes.FloorAreaCategories")
                .SingleAsync(x => x.Id == id);

var fts = project.FloorAreaTypes.ToList();
var fcs = fts.SelectMany(ft => ft.FloorAreaCategories).ToList();

DetachEntity(project);
DetachEntities(fts);
DetachEntities(fcs);

await _dbContext.AddAsync(project);
await _dbContext.AddRangeAsync(fts);
await _dbContext.AddRangeAsync(fcs);

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();


private T DetachEntity<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
    if (entity.GetType().GetProperty("Id") != null)
    {
        entity.GetType().GetProperty("Id").SetValue(entity, 0); // Id's must be set to 0 for a new object, even with no tracking
    }
    return entity;
}

private List<T> DetachEntities<T>(List<T> entities) where T : class
{
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        this.DetachEntity(entity);
    }
    return entities;
}
```

With some more time I'm sure this could be refactored to use Reflection with recursive functions for child objects based on a set of Include strings.